# philosophy of travel

Tags: society

I try, and practically cannot find works on this subject. I got Alain de Botton´s "The Art of Travel", found Santayana´s early essay, leafed through “The Ethics of Travel” by Sayed Manzurul Islam…

Do you know any other titles?

Comment: It's not particularly clear what you mean by "philosophy of travel" vs. "thoughts about travel" and what sort of dimensions you want to look at. Please clarify and make sure this fits the SE-model of an answerable question. (answerable meaning there is a correct answer rather than a list).

Comment: 'philosophy of tourism' is perhaps a better search target; more things in french as 'philosophie du voyage'; also 'homo viator'; and, lastly, a look at Maximiliano Korstanje in wikipedia for more ideas

Answer (score 1):

Count Hermann Keyserling's 'Travel Diary of a Philosopher' (1925) might be of interest.